# Use private npm repo in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, devops

We have a private npm repo hosted using sinopia it has basic auth credentials. And our application uses the npm package of the private repo. I created the authentication token and tried it but I am getting error at the line `RUN npm install utilities@0.1.9`:

> ```
> npm ERR! code E403
> npm ERR! 403 Forbidden: utilities@0.1.9
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-07-05T10_55_25_752Z-debug.log
> ```

And my `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./
RUN npm config set registry http://private.repo/:_authToken=CqgPS5l++vjD0n6ynxrVNg==.
RUN npm install utilities@0.1.9
RUN apk update && apk add yarn python g++ make && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN set NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN ls -al -R
EXPOSE 51967
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "pm2.json" ]
```

And the error log is:

> ```
> 11 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
> 11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
> 11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
> 11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
> 11 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
> 11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
> 11 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
> 11 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
> 11 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
> 11 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
> 11 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)
> ```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/docker-and-private-modules

Comment: @ippi Im also dng the same thing as you can see in my dockerFile but it is not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing the package `utilities@0.1.9` is your private package? If so, it would seem your auth token either isn't being used or doesn't have access to that package for some reason.

You could try writing the `~/.npmrc` file rather than using the config set, this would just be a case of using:

```
RUN echo -e "//private.repo/:_authToken=... > ~/.npmrc
```

This will cause your docker user to then authenticate using that token against the registry defined. This is how we setup auth tokens for npm for the most part.

On a side note, you might want to consider not using multiple RUN commands one after another. This causes a new image layer to be created for every single command and can bloat the size of your container massively. Try using `&& \` at the end of your commands and then placing the next command on a new line without the `RUN` bit. For example:

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./

RUN npm config set registry http://private.repo/:_authToken=$AUTH_TOKEN && \
  npm install utilities@0.1.9 && \
  apk update && apk add yarn python g++ make && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
  set NODE_ENV=production && \
  npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ && \
  npm install

COPY . /app

RUN ls -al -R

EXPOSE 51967

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "pm2.json" ]
```

It should be just as readable but the final image should be smaller and potentially a bit faster to build.

Comment: `On a side note, you might want to consider not using multiple RUN commands one after another`, furthermore, it might be security risk, check this article: [Securely using .npmrc files in Docker images](https://www.alexandraulsh.com/2018/06/25/docker-npmrc-security/).

Answer (score 2):

my solution is in dockerfile set configuration

```
ENV NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=https://privatedomain.com
ENV NPM_CONFIG_USERNAME=username
ENV NPM_CONFIG_EMAIL=my@email.com
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PASSWORD=my password

RUN npm set registry https://privatedomain.com
```

Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~21.04.2
node v17.0.1

### update

after a few hours of struggle, I manage to solve it

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.15

ARG NPM_REGISTRY
ARG NPM_TOKEN
ARG NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY

ENV NPM_DOCKER_REGISTRY=$NPM_REGISTRY
ENV NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=$NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY
ENV NPM_DOCKER_TOKEN=$NPM_TOKEN
ENV WORKDIR=/app

WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}
    
COPY . ${WORKDIR}
    
RUN echo "//${NPM_DOCKER_REGISTRY}/:_authToken="'"'${NPM_DOCKER_TOKEN}'"' > ${WORKDIR}/.npmrc
    
RUN npm i --yes
RUN npm run build

RUN rm -fr ${WORKDIR}/src
RUN rm -fr ${WORKDIR}/.npmrc

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

and execute build

```
NPM_REGISTRY=url NPM_TOKEN=token docker build -t name/xxx:node-alpine . \
  --build-arg NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=https://${NPM_REGISTRY} \
  --build-arg NPM_REGISTRY=${NPM_REGISTRY} \
  --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me i had to set the global flag **--location=global** and first specify the registry then the registry token

```
RUN npm config set registry https://private-repo/npm/default.npm.global --location=global
RUN npm config set //private-repo/npm/:_auth "MY TOKEN" --location=global
```